# (Unity2D) How to get the player to interact with a platform base on the color of their sprite?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

First-time poster - long time browser.

I am creating a system, where the player can only collide with objects that has the same color as their paintbrush (child sprite). The system works well enough when the color and string of the object are set randomly, but when I attempt to implement the system using UI buttons - it just ignores the string change.

```
    //VAR: Character Color
[Header("VAR Color Switch")]
public string currentColor;
public Color colorPrimary;
public Color colorSecondary;
public Color colorTertiary;
private GameObject child;
public SpriteRenderer sr;


private void Start() {
    child = transform.GetChild(0).gameObject; 
    sr = child.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>(); 

    SetRandomColor(); 

}

private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other) {
    switch(other.gameObject.tag)
    {
        case "Jumppad": 
            jumpForce = jumpBoost;
        break;
        case "Ground": 
            jumpForce = initialJumpForce;
        break;
        case "Primary":
            if(other.gameObject.tag == currentColor)
            {
                other.gameObject.GetComponent<Collider2D>().enabled = true;
            }else if (other.gameObject.tag != currentColor)
            {
                other.gameObject.GetComponent<Collider2D>().enabled = false;
            }
        break;
        case "Secondary":
            if(other.gameObject.tag == currentColor)
            {
                other.gameObject.GetComponent<Collider2D>().enabled = true;
            }else if (other.gameObject.tag != currentColor)
            {
                other.gameObject.GetComponent<Collider2D>().enabled = false;
            }
        break;
        case "Tertiary":
            if(other.gameObject.tag == currentColor)
            {
                other.gameObject.GetComponent<Collider2D>().enabled = true;
            }else if (other.gameObject.tag != currentColor)
            {
                other.gameObject.GetComponent<Collider2D>().enabled = false;
            }
        break;
    }
}


public void SetRandomColor()
{
    int index = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, 3);

    switch (index)
    {
        case 0:
            currentColor = "Primary";
            sr.color = colorPrimary;
        break;
        case 1:
            currentColor = "Secondary";
            sr.color = colorSecondary;
        break;
        case 2:
            currentColor = "Tertiary";
            sr.color = colorTertiary;
        break;
    }
}
```

}

Code on UI buttons

```
 PlayerController player;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    player = FindObjectOfType<PlayerController>();
}

public void SwitchPrimary()
{
    player.currentColor = "Primary";
    player.sr.color = player.colorPrimary;
}

public void SwitchSecondary()
{
    player.currentColor = "Secondary";
    player.sr.color = player.colorSecondary;
}

public void SwitchTertiary()
{
    player.currentColor = "Teritary";
    player.sr.color = player.colorTertiary;
}
```

I am genuinely unsure of what could be the problem. No matter what variation I attempt, I somehow get the same result.

Comment: Well given in the collider you check a tag that doesnt change..

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question but you can refactor some code in your switch to avoid duplication of code: `case "Primary": case "Secondary": case "Tertiary": // same code for all three... then break`

Comment: I believe `other.gameObject.tag` should be `other.gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color` instead.

Comment: @BugFinder Yeah, this seemingly was the issue. I instead used a function and called it in the update function. Don't believe this is the most effective method, but it worked.

Comment: @NicolásdeOry I couldn't call the colour from the sprite renderer because I was using tags and matching them with the gameObject. Changing the variable (currentColor) whenever the player picks the UI. It's all messy code, and I was just matching it to a game like colour switch.